# ckeditor - how to manage config changes

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor plugin that depends on some custom parameters. These parameters may change value over the course of operation. The way I ended up implementing this was to keep the current value in a local variable inside the plugin which is initialized at the beginning and can be changed through a custom command. Like so

```
var somethingId = editor.config.myplugin_Something;
editor.addCommand('changeSomething',  {
    exec: function(_editor, data) {
        somethingId = data.something;
    }
});
```

This works ok, but I'm having an issue where (from what I can tell) I'm reaching the situatino where I need to change the data, but the editor has not been initialized yet, so calling

```
$.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function (index, editor) {
    editor.execCommand('changeSomething', {
        something: newValue
        });
});
```

has no effect and the plugin ends up with the value that was passed in the initial config.

I can't think of a good way out of this short of using a global variable. Is there a better way to manage mutable config parameters for ckeditor plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that's simple enough. Use the `config` object itself, and also make sure the initialization *callback* sets the correct value as well.

So the initialization looks more like:

```
var config = { width: xxx, height: xxx}; // do not include "something" value
$('#mytextbox').ckeditor(function(){
    this.config.myplugin_somethingId = currentSomethingValue;
});
```

And when it needs to be modified later I do,

```
$.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function (index, editor) {
     editor.config.myplugin_somethingId = newSomethingValue;
});
```